# When I tried to create an app on vue-cli@4.5.13 it's getting stuck. How can I fix it?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, node-gyp, node-sass

Yesterday, I had tried to deploy a project on Netlify. And I got many errors after that I checked the logs on it and I decided to change my local environments. But now I couldn't create application on my local. I tried many things but I didn't find correct solution.

My environments are (similar with Netlify):

```
node version: 16.8.0
npm version: 7.21.0
global vue cli version is : @vue/cli@4.5.13
```

I am trying this settings from vue-cli

```
Vue CLI v4.5.13
? Please pick a preset: 
Manually select features

? Check the features needed for your project: 
Choose Vue version, Babel, Router, Vuex, CSS Pre-processors, Linter

? Choose a version of Vue.js that you want to start the project with 
2.x

? Use history mode for router? (Requires proper server setup for index fallback 
in production)
Yes

? Pick a CSS pre-processor (PostCSS, Autoprefixer and CSS Modules are supported 
by default): 
Sass/SCSS (with node-sass)

? Pick a linter / formatter config: 
Prettier

? Pick additional lint features: 
Lint on save

? Where do you prefer placing config for Babel, ESLint, etc.?
In package.json

? Save this as a preset for future projects? 
No
```

I tried many times and it always getting stuck on those two lines and then getting some errors

```
reify:prettier: http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/prettier/-/prettier-2.3.2.tgz

reify:prettier: timing reifyNode:node_modules/eslint Completed in 508ms
```

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/src -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/src -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o ../src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/src -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o ../src/libsass/src/backtrace.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/src -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o ../src/libsass/src/base64vlq.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/src -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/bind.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/bind.o ../src/libsass/src/bind.cpp
npm ERR!   cc '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/src -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cencode.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cencode.o ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/src -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/check_nesting.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/check_nesting.o ../src/libsass/src/check_nesting.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/src -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/color_maps.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/color_maps.o ../src/libsass/src/color_maps.cpp
npm
```

...

```
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/src -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch arm64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o ../src/binding.cpp
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.8.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.16
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.8.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.8.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.8.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.8.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.8.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:98780) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture arm64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir /Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp:2:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable 'denominator' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! 2 warnings generated.
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.cpp:1:
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators)
npm ERR!                         ^
```

...

```
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable 'denominator' creates a copy from type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!                         ^
npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' to prevent copying
npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator : denominators)
npm ERR!              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                         &
npm ERR! 2 warnings generated.
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:58:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node/node.h:63:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node/v8.h:30:
npm ERR! /Users/alex/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:488:38: error: no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'remove_cv'?
npm ERR!             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                                      remove_cv
npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:776:50: note: 'remove_cv' declared here
npm ERR! template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_cv
npm ERR!                                                  ^
npm ERR! 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/alex/workspace/new-project/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alex/.npm/_logs/2021-08-29T20_04_52_558Z-debug.log
 ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete your package.lock.json + node_modules folder, and cleared npm cache with `npm cache clean --force`? Then reinstall everything with npm install. This often works wonders.

Comment: Yeap, I tried even uninstalling nodejs and npm. Nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

After all, I completely uninstall node again, npm and cleared my cache. I installed `nvm` and then started to tried node versions and my conclusions are:

1. node **v15.0.0** fix to create vue app problem but it couldn't solve Netlify deployment problem.
2. node **v14.17.5** works but it was the starting point my problem (deploying on Netlify)
3. If you want to deploy your project on Netlify. You could define `NODE_VERSION`. Check it out [Node.js and JavaScript](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/manage-dependencies/#node-js-and-javascript) and [Build environment variables](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/)

Ps: Those results are based on vue cli settings which are mentioned above in question.

Comment: this reads like a comment to your question. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I solved. Thank you. I installed node v14.17.5 using nvm. I create an vue app which based from above settings. After that I defined NODE_VERSION on Netlify and I deployed.